# Fetching all columns from one and some from the other

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using **spark scala**. I've two dataframes that I want to join and select all columns from the first and a few from the second.
This is mu code, that doesn't work,

```
val df = df1.join(df2,
      df1("a") <=> df2("a")
      && df1("b") <=> df2("b"),
      "left").select(df1("*"),---> is this correct?
      df2("c AS d", "e AS f")) ---> fails here
```

This fails with the following error,

```
too many arguments for method apply: (colName: String)org.apache.spark.sql.Column in class Dataset
      df2("c AS d", "e AS f"))
```

I couldn't find a different method in the API to do it.

How do I do this.

Comment: try doing this --> select(df1("*"),df2("c).alias("d"),df2("e").alias("f")))

Answer (score 0):

Try using Aliases. I don't know in scala, but below code is in python/pyspark to join and get all columns from one table and some column from another table

```
df1_col =df1.columns 
 resultdf= df1.alias('left_table') \
            .join(df2.alias('right_table'),f.col('left_table.col1') == f.col('right_table.col1')) \
            .select(
            [f.col('left_table.' + xx) for xx in df1_col] + [f.col('right_table.col2'),f.col('right_table.col3'),f.col('right_table.col4')])
```

Comment: You chose to answer a different question altogether - the question is very specific about the requirement - the scala API.

Comment: 'Alias' is spark specific not related to python or Scala and 'for loop' in select condition there might an similar function in Scala or you can manual enter all the column names. This was just an example on how you could proceed with it. I just googled on how to select all columns in Scala, you could do select('left_table'. *)  or you create a list with all columns names and apply map function to convert to column object and use it in select statement. It might not be answer to what to you wanted but you just had to google to get an idea based on above answer.